# Web Deploy Package Isn't Zipped

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Using VS 2013's Publish Profile I can NOT get the package output to zip as part of the publish.  If I give a target of xx.zip I just get a folder named that and files are all unzipped under the folder.

Using the publish wizard now, but hoping to create msbuild command line.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\dev\Cloud_Deploy_Package\deployMe.zip</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Try publishing with `FTP` method?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (unfortunately, I closed the browser so I can't link).  You have to create a Web Deploy Package and NOT a Filesystem package.  Right-click project, Publish..., select "Web Deploy Package"...

The result is a folder with a few text files and a big ole zip of your project!